# can not install speed dreams in my ubuntu 14.10

Tags: command-line

The error is

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 speed-dreams : Depends: speed-dreams-base but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should search the existing answers before posting. Your problem is described and solved here:

[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)